# Data on forest production in Europe

Tags: geospatial, europe

I am wondering if there are some GIS (Geographical Information System) resources for finding data on forest production in Europe, e.g. raster data depicting yearly production of beech hard mast (Fagus sylvatica) or other tree species, in order to perform some studies on the influence of this parameter on some animal species.

Perhaps something obtained from remote sensing. Any suggestion?